# Disable barcode scanner on preview window closing

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner

When I close the preview window of my `BarcodeScanner` the webcam stay active and I want to prevent that because it's kind of weird to see that the camera is still on and that you can still scan some barcode even if I close the preview.

I can't figure out how to disable the `BarcodeScanner` when I close the preview window.

Here's my 'BarcodeScanner' code :

```cs
private async Task<bool> ClaimScanner()
{
    bool res = false;

    string selector = BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector();
    DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

    if(scanner == null)
        scanner = await BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceCollection[0].Id);

    if (scanner != null)
    {
        if(claimedBarcodeScanner == null)
            claimedBarcodeScanner = await scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();

        if (claimedBarcodeScanner != null)
        {
            claimedBarcodeScanner.DataReceived += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync;
            claimedBarcodeScanner.ReleaseDeviceRequested += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_ReleaseDeviceRequested;
            claimedBarcodeScanner.IsDecodeDataEnabled = true;
            claimedBarcodeScanner.IsDisabledOnDataReceived = true;
            await claimedBarcodeScanner.EnableAsync();

            res = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Barcode Scanner claimed");
        }
    }
    antispam = false;
    return res;
}

public async void ScanBarcodeAsync()
{
    if(claimedBarcodeScanner == null && !antispam)
    {
        antispam = true;
        await ClaimScanner();
    }
    if(claimedBarcodeScanner != null)
    {
        await claimedBarcodeScanner.ShowVideoPreviewAsync();
        await claimedBarcodeScanner.StartSoftwareTriggerAsync();
        claimedBarcodeScanner = null;
    }
}

private async void ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (currentDataContext != null && currentDataContext is Scannable)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, args.Report.ScanDataLabel));
                Scannable obj = (Scannable)currentDataContext;
                obj.NumSerie = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, args.Report.ScanDataLabel);
            }
        }
    );
}

void ClaimedBarcodeScanner_ReleaseDeviceRequested(object sender, ClaimedBarcodeScanner e)
{
    // always retain the device
    e.RetainDevice();
}
```

EDIT : I used the library indicated by Microsoft provided by Digimarc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-camerabarcode

Comment: Can you mention which library you used for barcode reading

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: @Reaperino, Does the following answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disable barcode scanner on preview window closing

`ClaimedBarcodeScanner` has `StopSoftwareTriggerAsync` method, if you want to disable barcode scanner on preview window closing, you just invoke [`StopSoftwareTriggerAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.claimedbarcodescanner.stopsoftwaretriggerasync) method after `HideVideoPreview`.

```
private async void HidePreviewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    claimedScanner?.HideVideoPreview();
    await claimedScanner?.StopSoftwareTriggerAsync();   
}
```

Comment: Ok that could work but I am using the default preview window not a custom preview, so I wonder if I could get the event when I close that window.

Comment: The above code  is default preview window,  and ClaimedBarcodeScanner class  does not provide such event that triggered when preview close.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your first answer but now I got it. Will try and give you some news.